# How to Draw D3 Bar chart With Zooming Option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am using D3 bar chart, for this chart the data is in large amount,
i want to see that data  by zooming this chart or else it will be good if i will get that scrolling option on x axis......
but i don't know how to make it.
I am New to this environment please help me to find the answer for this question
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does "zooming this chart" mean  bar is too long and you want to make it fit to screen ?
 
Would you mind capturing your chart  ?

Or something like graph in this link ? http://c3js.org/samples/interaction_zoom.html

It's Line chart, and you can scroll to see the zoom feature

Comment: Exactly sir but i am not getting this one i tried in Google, i got same thing but i don't know to make it

Comment: this is my code sir, i don't know where should i add that zoom option                                                                                                       <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered ;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

Comment: You can use Zoom behavior : https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior

For example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708  and http://bl.ocks.org/sgruhier/1d692762f8328a2c9957

Answer (score 0):

You can use the zoom event of d3:

```
d3.behavior.zoom()
```

This is the explanation from d3 documentation:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior

And there are other good examples with code, like:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708

http://bl.ocks.org/godds/ec089a2cf3e06a2cd5fc

http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1182434

http://jsfiddle.net/qkHK6/912/